# What mistake am I making when trying to pass data from my UIView to my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an educational app for kids; as of now, there is a "Hint Button" and a UILabel on the screen showing how many times a kid asks for a hint.

Pressing the hint button shows a popUp (UIView) where the kid can confirm that s/he wants a hint by pressing yet another button. Now I wish to increment the original UILabel by one and save this new incremented number to userDefaults once this second button on the popUp UIView is pressed.

While my code manages to save the incremented number to userDefaults, the UILabel does not reflect this change until the app is killed and restarted.

I would appreciate some help; I don't know what I'm missing. (Do let me know if this question is not suited for this site, I'll remove it.)

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let hintButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Hint me!", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
        let pop = Popup()
        self.view.addSubview(pop)
    }

    var numberOfHintsRequested: Int {
           get {
               return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "hintsRequestedSaved")
           }
           set {
               UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "hintsRequestedSaved")
           }
       }

    lazy var hintsAskedLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 50)
        label.text = String(numberOfHintsRequested)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(hintButton)
        view.addSubview(hintsAskedLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        hintButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        hintButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
        hintButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        hintButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

        hintsAskedLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        hintsAskedLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
        hintsAskedLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hintButton.topAnchor, constant: -180),
        hintsAskedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)

    ])

        }
    }
```

And here is my UIView:

```
class Popup: UIView {

    fileprivate let showHintButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Hint me NOW!!", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showHintButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return button
    }()

    @objc func showHintButtonPressed() {
        print("ZABOOKA")
        ViewController().numberOfHintsRequested += 1
        let text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "hintsRequestedSaved")
        if let unwrappedText = text {
            ViewController().hintsAskedLabel.text = unwrappedText as? String
        } else {
         print("NEHEHEHE")
        }
        print(ViewController().numberOfHintsRequested)
        self.containerDisappear()
    }

    fileprivate let container: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 24
        return v
    }()

    @objc fileprivate func containerDisappear() {
            self.alpha = 0
    }

    @objc fileprivate func containerAppear() {
        self.alpha = 1
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(containerDisappear)))
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        self.addSubview(container)

        container.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
        container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.45).isActive = true

        container.addSubview(showHintButton)
        showHintButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        showHintButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        showHintButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        showHintButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.15).isActive = true

        containerAppear()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("BAD")
    }
}
```

Comment: The title of your question is "What mistake am I making when trying to pass date from my UIView to my UIViewController?". Don't you mean to ask about passing **data**, not a **date**?

Comment: @DuncanC, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake.

Any call of `ViewController()` creates a brand new instance of the view controller, in `showHintButtonPressed` you are creating three different instances.

A *swifty* solution is a callback closure.

In `PopUp` add a property

```
var callback : (() -> Void)?
```

and replace

```
@objc func showHintButtonPressed() {
    print("ZABOOKA")
    ViewController().numberOfHintsRequested += 1
    let text = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "hintsRequestedSaved")
    if let unwrappedText = text {
        ViewController().hintsAskedLabel.text = unwrappedText as? String
    } else {
     print("NEHEHEHE")
    }
    print(ViewController().numberOfHintsRequested)
    self.containerDisappear()
}
```

with

```
@objc func showHintButtonPressed() {
     callback?()
     self.containerDisappear()
}
```

Another mistake is that you are saving an `Int` to `UserDefaults` in `ViewController` and retrieving it as `String` will always fail.

---

In `ViewController` replace

```
@objc func buttonPressed() {
    let pop = Popup()
    self.view.addSubview(pop)
}
```

with

```
@objc func buttonPressed() {
    let pop = Popup()
    pop.callback = { 
        var numberOfHints = self.numberOfHintsRequested
        numberOfHints += 1
        self.hintsAskedLabel.text = String(numberOfHints)
        self.numberOfHintsRequested = numberOfHints
    }
    self.view.addSubview(pop)
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer as always. (Voted). Others hinted around about various problems with the OPs code. I was getting ready to post a more complete answer until I saw yours. You covered everything I was going to say, along with providing a nice elegant solution using a closure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're creating a new `ViewController` object each time. It would be best to use a delegate to communicate this change to your existing reference of `ViewController`.

You can learn more about the delegate pattern and protocols here:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/

Example

```
protocol PopupDelegate: class {
    func popupViewDidTapActionButton(_ popup: Popup)
}

class Popup: UIView {

    weak var delegate: PopupDelegate?

    @objc func showHintButtonPressed() {
        delegate?.popupViewDidTapActionButton(self)
    }
}

class MyController: UIViewController {

    func showpopUp() {
        let pop = Popup()
        pop.delegate = self
    }
}

extension MyController: PopupDelegate {

    func popupViewDidTapActionButton(_ popup: Popup) {
        //UPDATE YOUR UI
    }
}
```

Comment: *It would be best to use a delegate*. I disagree, not in Swift.

Comment: Would be very interested in hearing your thoughts as to why not? (I do understand if this not the best forum, if so apologies)

Comment: Short answer: A native Swift pattern is more efficient than a pattern which has to be exposed to Objective-C